# How do IP-packets actually look like?

Tags: binary, header, ip, protocols, packet

How do i intepret such diagrams as in the given picture? Does it mean in the binary stream, first there is the first line of the diagram(i.e. octet 0 in the figure) and then the second line and so on?

[Ip-Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34MG1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The IP header is just a long string of `0`s and `1`s (a.k.a. bits), without any line break or interruption.

The picture you linked shows the IP header in a handy format for humans: instead of writing everything in a single, long horizontal line, it visually breaks the string every 32 bits.

It also tells you the length of each field: for example, the `version` field goes from bit number 0 to bit number 3 (4 bits long), while `source address` goes from bit 96 to bit 127 (32 bits long  starting at bit 96, i.e. octet 12).

Sources and additional info: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure), [here](https://internalpointers.com/post/introduction-ip-internet-protocol).